# Split available width between two images (placed side by side) by stretching/shrinking the images (without using `width = 50%`)?

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to place two identically sized images side by side. I want both of them to have the same width, and be as wide as possible while preserving aspect ratio. Of course respecting the margins set in css.

```html
<style>
div.twoImg > img {
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="twoImg">
    <img src="http://www.halmstad.se/images/18.23a25fbe14937ab15f72ddfc/1415104727203/Skintan_avlopp460.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.halmstad.se/images/18.23a25fbe14937ab15f72ddfc/1415104727203/Skintan_avlopp460.jpg">
</div>
```

I could use `width = 50%` but I don't want to have to think about changes in the padding etc. What other alternatives are there?

Comment: _“but I don't want to have to think about changes in the padding etc”_ – use `box-sizing`, and you don’t have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/20/

the `calc` is setting 50% of the screen minus the margin width.

```
div.twoImg > img {
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Would `box-sizing = border-box` do the same?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver `box-sizing = margin-box` would do. But there is no such value as `margin-box` in box-sizing

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver as c-smile mentioned, you could use them both. see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/21/ `border-box` will take care of anything from your borders in, and the margin will be taken care of with the `calc`